# Discrepancy in SQL result when joining tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a query that will return all movies in SAKILA database that have french as the original language. The expected result is 0 rows.

When I use `language_id` to find titles with french as the language, I get the expected result:

```
SELECT title, release_year FROM sakila.film WHERE language_id =5;
```

However,
I'm trying to get this result without using literals`(language_id)`, and instead joining the two tables to select the film's original language.

When I write:

```
SELECT title, release_year
FROM sakila.film, sakila.language
WHERE language.name = 'french';
```

I get all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you don't want to use join, you need to add one condition inside where.

```
SELECT title, release_year
FROM sakila.film, sakila.language
WHERE language.name = 'french' and film.language_id = language.id
```

Comment: I think this is very close. I am getting one error. "Unknown column 'language.id' in 'where clause'." Could this have to do with the fact that `language` is a keyword?

Comment: Can you try changing language.id to language.language_id ? It depends on what column is the id for table language.

Comment: *In case you don't want to use join*: This is still a join, only that it uses the legacy and obsolete join syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify any join condition between your 2 tables. As a result, the query is generating a cartesian product, definitely not what you want.

Had you used the ANSI-style join, the syntax would have nudged you in the right direction:

```
select f.title, f.release_year
  from film f
  join language l
    on l.language_id = f.language_id -- you are missing this join condition
   and l.name = 'french'
```